# Detecting very smalls objects

Tags: opencv, templates, match

I think, this one is very difficult (at least for me).

This is the original image: [image: original image]

I want to detect this: [image: detected object]

I have the 2 originals images of theses objects: [image: red object] and [image: blue object]

I have a mask to narrow the result of search, because i dont need to find on "all images": [image: mask]

I have too a "state of clean" image" too:  [image: clean image]

I have tried templates matching using mask on the objects and in grey (because match template with color does not work with mask). Before template matching, i resize tiny objects to 0.66x the original size to match the height of "10/12px". It does not work very well.

I really dunno what to do.

Comment: You have some really specific token shape. I would suggest a [haar cascade](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/06/20/detecting-cats-in-images-with-opencv/) or similar. Although IMO this question is too broad for SO in it's current format

Comment: thx, you give me a track to follow ;)

Comment: I would start with subtracting (or xor-ing) the 'state of clean' image. How is the input image generated? Do you have influence on that generation?

Comment: Hi, sorry for answering late. Input image are taken from youtube videos, i have no influence on generation. I have follow a track: Taking red/blue range only, doing some dilatation => new mask, applying on original => doing match templatings so i have a lots of small images (only good and false positive) => classifying my self on red / blue and trash => training a deep learning classifier. It's works nearly like a charm but it's very very complicated :/ and slow